# Cannot get php-fpm on apache working?

Tags: performance, apache, fastcgi, php

I want to install php-fpm for my server
my server is running on Apache, PHP 5.3.20, Fastcgi

and I also install php-fpm, using yum install php-fpm

but now I look at phpinfo page, the Server API still shows CGI/FastCGI instead of FPM/FastCGI
but when I use ps -ef | grep php-fpm I can get

```
    apache   30304 30303  0 08:08 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
    apache   30305 30303  0 08:08 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
    apache   30306 30303  0 08:08 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
    apache   30307 30303  0 08:08 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
    apache   30308 30303  0 08:08 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
    root     30494 29917  0 08:32 pts/0    00:00:00 grep php-fpm
```

is my php-fpm working or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you decided to install PHP as a package, did you make certain to only install the FPM package and not the PHP package? By having both installed this would cause this situation to happen. Most package managers split their PHP installations by ISAPI. If you have installed both, remove one of them and try again. The your post it appears FPM is running, but your previous installation is probably causing it not to be picked up yet.

I also have a GitHub Gist for configuration of PHP-FPM and Apache 2.4 (works with 2.2 too with minor apache configuration changes) -> https://gist.github.com/diemuzi/3849349